# VBA Using Regular Expressions to Split a String

Tags: regex, vba, split, delimiter

Hoping someone may be able to offer a better approach to what I am doing. Unfortunately the data and code sit on client systems so I can't share them.

I have this long string which was previously a data table and need to split up the values into rows and columns again. The system is heavily locked down so I am limited to using VBA. The best way I can think of is to use regular expressions to identify columns and rows. I've set up my regular expression object and executed against the input string, have all the matches I need which is fine. The problem is that if I do

```
re = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
re.pattern = mypattern
re.split(myString)
```

As far as I can see there is no way to retain the values I am splitting on. In some cases I want to split in the middle of the regex string anyway.

The most promising solution I think is to do

```
re = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
re.pattern = mypattern
Set matches = re.execute(myString)
for each match in matches:
    'do something with match.firstindex
```

I considered just inserting delimiters and then using split. Unfortunately VBA seems to have no method to insert a character into a string it looks a bit clunky to use the firstindex.

Does anyone have any thoughts on better approaches? Much appreciated if so.

Comment: Without any  - even dummy - data it is not clear how to help.

Comment: Pretty sure `matches` needs to be an object reference and thus assigned using the `Set` keyword. Question: why aren't you using early-binding to work with API's you're unfamiliar with?

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts. I will try to share a better description of the data/string later.  I hadn't come across the term early binding but looks like I am using it. I just typed he above code in the stackoverflow editor as I don't have access to the code I am actually using. Yes, I think set keyword is required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually can insert characters into a string. Depends on your definition of "clunky" but here's an example:

```
ActiveCell.Characters(5, 1).Insert (" | ")
```

This will put a " | " starting at the fifth character of the cell. You might need to identify some positions using find or some loops through the cell characters, but I think that might get you on your way.

**UPDATED WITH STRING EDIT**
This is just my preference but editing string doesn't seem too clunky. You can use this setup to probably get what you want:

```
Sub StringSlicerSample()
Dim teststring As String, Separater As String, tangoTxt As String, BeforeTXT As String, AfterTxt As String, MidTxt As String
Dim Position_To_Slice As Integer

teststring = "xxxbangyyy"    
Separater = " | " 'can be whatever you want as separator    
tangoTxt = "bang" 'text to look for that you want use for split
Position_To_Slice = 1 'If you want to split somewhere in between, lets say after the "b"
'put =1 as that's the first position in "bang"

'Insert separator before
BeforeTXT = Mid(teststring, 1, InStr(1, teststring, tangoTxt) - 1) & Separater & Mid(teststring, InStr(1, teststring, tangoTxt), Len(teststring))

'Insert after
AfterTxt = Mid(teststring, 1, InStr(1, teststring, tangoTxt) + Len(tangoTxt) - 1) & Separater & Mid(teststring, InStr(1, teststring, tangoTxt) + Len(tangoTxt), Len(teststring))

'Split inbetween based on position to slice
MidTxt = Mid(teststring, 1, InStr(1, teststring, tangoTxt) + Position_To_Slice - 1) & Separater & Mid(teststring, InStr(1, teststring, tangoTxt) + Position_To_Slice, Len(teststring))


MsgBox BeforeTXT, Title:="Before Example"
MsgBox AfterTxt, Title:="After Example"
MsgBox MidTxt, Title:="Sliced in position " & Position_To_Slice

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, that's useful. I was looking at adding to a VBA string rather than directly in a cell. I could change my approach a bit to make use of his method though.

Comment: See updated answer if you want to use string. Seems not too complex?

Comment: I'll accept as the answer, I think this is the best approach I can envisage. +1 for making a sensible guess at the type of data I was working with